# How to create a loop from an array at a specified index with ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I wrote a loop script from an array like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a.cycle.each{|i| p i; sleep 1}
```

And I want to start a loop from a specified index.

```
index = 2
(a[index..-1] + a.cycle).each{|i| p i; sleep 1}
```

This code ends up with error `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Enumerator into Array`.

How can I write a loop code like this case?

Comment: It says in the docs that if no block is given to cycle it returns an enumerator instead hence the type error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `rotate`:

```
a.rotate(new_index).cycle { ... }
```

(NOTE: I don't think you need the `.each`)

Answer (score 2):

`rotate` is the correct answer, but the reason your code wasn't working was because you were trying to concatenate the last part of the array and `a.cycle`, which is an `Enumerator` and probably not what you wanted. Furthermore, your code would output `[3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]` (if you fixed the other part) because you don't slice off the end when you concatenate the rest of the array.

Try this instead (actually, use `rotate` like @lurker said, but here's how to fix your original code):

```
(a[index..-1] + a[0...index]).cycle {|i| p i; sleep 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it without [Array#rotate](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-rotate). Suppose that for:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

the starting index were `2`:

```
enum = a.cycle
2.times { enum.next }
enum.each { |i| p i; sleep 1 }
```